# partial processing of a PrimeFaces datatable column

Tags: primefaces, datatable, selector, partial

I am trying to implement an undo button for rows of a datatable. I would like to undo all selected rows at once. For that purpose, the datatable has a selection column that allows multiple selection and a command button that executes the undo method of the view's backing bean.

My problem is that I cannot figure out which PrimeFaces selector to use in order to process only the selection column. I have tried every selector I deemed reasonable (and some weird ones too) but it is like the whole datatable is always processed. So, if there is an error in the data of any row, validation fails and the undo operation cannot be performed.

Relevant lines of my xhtml file follow:

```
<p:dataTable
    id="dataTable"
    var="currentRow"
    value="#{viewBean.rows}"
    selection="#{viewBean.selectedRows}">
    <p:column id="selectionColumn" selectionMode="multiple"/>

    several columns here

    <f:facet name="footer">
        <p:commandButton
            id="undoButton"
            action="#{viewBean.undo()}"
            partialSubmit="true"
            process="@(.ui-selection-column)"
            update="dataTable"
            value="undo"/>
   </f:facet>
</p:dataTable>
```

So far I have tried:

```
process="@(.ui-selection-column)"
process="@(:checkbox)"
process="@(.ui-selection-column :checkbox)"
process="@(#dataTable :checkbox)"
process="@(#mainForm\:dataTable :checkbox)"
process="@(#mainForm\:dataTable\:selectionColumn)"
```

As I said before, none of them work; it is like the whole datatable is always processed.

Comment: Please only use the [tag:processing] tag for questions about the Processing language.

Comment: I've noticed a similar problem with dialogs. All fields in the dialog seem to be processed regardless of the process option specified in the "hide" button (process="@this")